# Inserting value using one App and Retrieving value from another apps showing no such table found-Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

hi friends i created  database and created a table and inserted some values using one android app. and i tried to retrieve a value from that table that was created from different app shows no such table. please anyone help

```
try
{
        Toast.makeText(ArrayPhoneActivity.this, "In try ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Emergency.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , OPEN_READWRITE);

        String qu="select * from userinfos";
        c=db.rawQuery(qu,null);

        int count = c.getCount();

        String[] values = new String[count + 1];
        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
           values[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mail"));
           Toast.makeText(ArrayPhoneActivity.this, values[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           i++;
        }
```

Comment: Can u show ur code for reading?

Comment: i shown please see @KanakSony

Comment: check these - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474991/no-such-table-issue-in-android-on-some-devices and http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html

Comment: I cant understand.please tell shortly what i have to change